# Crear una estructura JSON a partir de un Ajax en javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, array, object

necesito de su apoyo para crear una estructura que se ocupa para llenar un organigrama con *javascript*.

Tengo un servicio web en la url **ajax/datos_organigrama.php?action=ajax_trabajadores_organigrama** que consulto mediante un *AJAX* y me devuelve un objeto tipo *JSON* con varios resultados

[image: Response de un JSON devuelto por la petición AJAX]

Lo que estoy intentando hacer es formar un estructura con esta respuesta para poder mostrar un organigrama, .. la estructura que se requiere es la siguiente (marcada por la línea roja):

[image: Estructura a formar con el JSON]

Y quiero saber como puedo llenar la estructura del organigrama **data_nodes** (lo que esta en comentarios), con el json que me devuelve mi web service...

Comment: Si tu eres el que devuelve de PHP el resultado, por que no lo devuelves como lo necesitas. Osea en ves de poner `id_trabajador`, le llamas `id`, `tr_nombre` como `name`

Comment: Es que ese web service lo consumimos desde otros lados, entonces estoy intentando no afectar lo demás...

Comment: Entiendo, entonces puedes copiar un registro del response, ya que en la imagen solo se ven 4 atributos y lo que necesitas tiene 4, pero no esta la imagen, ni titulo, entonces para poder hacer una respuesta necesitaría el resto

Comment: Así es como esta conformado cada uno de los nodos

{"status":"ok",
 "result [
    {"id_trabajador":1,
     "tr_codigo":"000000",
     "tr_nombre":"NOMBRE_1",
     "tr_apellido_paterno":"APELLIDO_1",
     "puesto_nombre":"PUESTO_1",
     "id_responsableDirecto":000000,
     "asistente":0,
     "url_imagen":"url-de-la-imagen.jpg"}
   ]
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De la respuesta que te devuelve el backend, tome el valor de `result`, donde itere por este y retorno la nueva estructura esperada.

```js
var rs = [ 
 {"id_trabajador":1, "tr_codigo":"000000", "tr_nombre":"NOMBRE_1", "tr_apellido_paterno":"APELLIDO_1", "puesto_nombre":"PUESTO_1", "id_responsableDirecto":000000, "asistente":0, "url_imagen":"url-de-la-imagen.jpg"}, 
 {"id_trabajador":2, "tr_codigo":"000000", "tr_nombre":"NOMBRE_2", "tr_apellido_paterno":"APELLIDO_2", "puesto_nombre":"PUESTO_2", "id_responsableDirecto":000000, "asistente":0, "url_imagen":"url-de-la-imagen.jpg"},
 {"id_trabajador":3, "tr_codigo":"000000", "tr_nombre":"NOMBRE_3", "tr_apellido_paterno":"APELLIDO_3", "puesto_nombre":"PUESTO_3", "id_responsableDirecto":000000, "asistente":0, "url_imagen":"url-de-la-imagen.jpg"} 
 ];


var resultado = rs.map( function(row) {
 var newRow = {  
   "id": row.id_trabajador,
      "name": `${row.tr_nombre} ${row.tr_apellido_paterno}`,
      "title": row.puesto_nombre,
      "img": row.url_imagen
    }
    return newRow;
 });

console.log(resultado);
```